# How to color auto-echoed charactes in curses?

Tags: python, colors, curses, python-curses

curses.echo() prints every hit key. I know how to change color when using addstr, but I don't know how to print some auto-echoed letters in red.

Answer (score 1):

That's done by setting the *window attributes* with a color-pair for red, e.g., using [*window*.**`attron`**(*attr*)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.attron)